# how to reload externally renewed kerberos ticket cache into jvm

Tags: java, authentication, apache-kafka, kerberos, logback

I am suffering from this issue a lot. Any help will be of great importance.

I am using [kafka appender](https://github.com/danielwegener/logback-kafka-appender) library to push logs to logstash.
I am using kerberos authentication method to connect to kafka broker.
At the start of my app, everything works fine and I am able to connect to kafka brokers.
Below are few producer configs I am providing.

```
 <producerConfig>sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.krb5LoginModule
required
ticketCache="path-to-my-ticket-cache"
useTicketCache="true"
refreshKrb5Config="true"
doNotPrompt="true"
principal="myprincipal@realm";
</producerConfig>
```

- When I hit this command - `klist -c path-to-my-ticket-cache` , I see it's getting renewed after every 2 hours but the same renewed time is not reflecting in my java app. The app still shows the initial expiry time loaded at startup and it destroys the ticket after expiry and authentication starts failing.

Few Things I tried,

- Added **renewTgt** property to producer config, it tried to renew but failed with error- cannot find /tmp/krb5cc123 cache to renew the ticket.

How we can force the app to read the ticket from the main cache which is getting renewed but JVM seems not aware of it?

Comment: The Java implementation of Kerberos can read the shared cache, but cannot write in it -- think of that as a compatibility layer with legacy stuff (i.e. circa 1990). You can create your own private, in-memory ticket via JAAS configuration -- via passwords (interactive mode) or keytab files (headless mode).

Comment: The `renewTGT` property looks like sthg that was in the roadmap but never was actually implemented.

Comment: In your case, I would guess that your Linux authentication is handled via SSSD (or Centrify) bound to an external LDAP directory w/ Kerberos support (RedHat IPA or Microsoft Active Directory), and the system daemon renews/recreates your Kerberos ticket automatically. But Java only reads the cache at startup. Did you try to **catch the error** then reset the JAAS config dynamically and retry?

Comment: To debug the JAAS config & login sequence (and detect issues that are silently ignored by default!!!) you must set a debug flag -- only way to understand what really happens at run-time: `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​,logincontext`

Comment: Hi Samson, thanks for your reply.! As I am giving those producer config to Kafka appender library, I have no control over catching error. You identified it right. My start up cache is getting renewed by other system thread but JVM is not able to reload it. Also, I tried renewTgt option but it throws error saying some /tmp/krb5cc123* is not available. (*123-random number).

Comment: That would be the default ticket cache using `FILE:` storage i.e. `/tmp/krb5cc_<your-user-id>` and your Linux user ID is _not_ random. I guess the 123 prefix is used to separate users mapped from an external LDAP and local users (starting at 1 for _root_). Try to run commands such as `id` and `getent passwd <your-user-name>`

Comment: Yes, you are right. its fixed number and not random. I tried running '/usr/bin/kinit -c cache-location -R' command and that renewed the ticket fine. When I kept renewTgt=true and gave the same command to 'sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd' parameter, Java is trying to renew the ticket but it's throwing 'no such file or directory' exception. any way to overcome that?

Comment: may be poor implementation. below code snip says it only takes string as a kinit command whereas processbuilder needs array of string in case of params.  log.debug("[Principal={}]: Running ticket cache refresh command: {} {}", new Object[]{this.principal, this.kinitCmd, kinitArgs});
                Shell.execCommand(new String[]{this.kinitCmd, kinitArgs});
                break;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227599/discussion-between-tukaram-bhosale-and-samson-scharfrichter).

Comment: My issue is closely related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9908.   
On top of that, I found I cant supply params to kinit command config as it accepts only plain string and not array. This is causing ProcessBuilder failure to run kinit command.   
The only option remaining is to try the workaround suggested in the above issue.